# Two Gang switch wiring for two separate devices Australian standards

Tags: wiring

I am raplacing the old two gang switch with a similar new one ( simple circuitry for two devices operating independently).

Kindly help me identify the correct wiring before removing old wiring which appears to be unclear. An explicit diagram for where the Live (Red) and neutral (Black) wires should be connected with the new switch with four points would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Wiring at present
[image]
New two gang switch connectors
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The four points are `one`, `common`, `loop`, and `two` (  two has the breakable T-shaped barrier over it,  common is the middle of the three, loop is the odd man out.

Each switch is an SPDT switch which in the the normal on position electrically connects common and one, and in the normal off position connects common and two instead.

loop makes no electrical connection, it's just there as a convenience to join wires together.

I can see in your photo all the black neutrals are connected together using one of the loop connectors.

The live feed comes in to one switch's common  and then a short link goes from there to the common on the other switch, and the live feed departs on another wire from the other switch to places unknown (probably to the the back of yet another switch somewhere nearby).
The load wires to the two loads connect to the one terminals one to each switch.

How to copy the wiring, draw a picture of the switches from behind and number the used terminals 0,1,2,3  (mark the one where the neutrals go 'N' for 'neutral' or 'noir') then using a permanent marker or ball point pen put 0,1,2 or 3  bands on the red wires so that you know which hole to put them in afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Appreciate it Jasen.

Comment: @handyman, please take the [tour] to see the proper way of saying "thanks" around here. If this solved your problem, please also be sure to click the check mark.